# Make two transparent images overlap using CSS

Tags: css, image, transparency, overlap

I'm trying to make two transparent images (having the same size/dimension) overlap within a `div` at their top left corners. I tried:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
<div style="margin:20px;">
<div id="main" style="overflow:hidden;background-color:red;width:400px;height:400px;border:3px solid blue;">
<img src="myimage1.png" style="position:relative;top:0px;left:0px;z-index:0;"/>
<img src="myimage2.png" style="position:relative;top:0px;left:0px;z-index:10;"/>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But that doesn't work. Instead, the two pictures are concatenated within the parent `div`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to make `#main` have `position:relative`, then change the two `<img>`'s to use `position:absolute`.

Comment: beat me to it--here's a live example http://jsbin.com/unogu3/ (I offset the images to show they overlap--obviously yours would be a little different)

Answer (score 1):

make the second image `position:absolute` and #main `position:relative`

Answer (score 0):

Just a note:

`position:relative` and `position:absolute` refer to `0;0` of closest parent, which has `position:relative` or `position:absolute`. If none of your `div`s has, then it refers to `0;0` (top;left) of document (`body`).

`position:relative` - top and left refer to difference between natural flow value of element - i.e. if "image" has natural flow `x` 1500 and `y` 1200, `top: 150px; left: -50px;` will move it to `x: 1450; y: 1350;`

`position:absolute` - top and left are aligned against `0;0` of closest `p:r` or `p:a` parent element, regardless of natural flow - ex. (in pseudo html/css):

```
<div style="relative/absolute">
  <img absolute="top:-20px; left: 150px;">
</div>
```

Image will be 20px higher and 150px to the right from left top corner of parent div.

That said, you want your container either relative and absolute and both of your stacked images should be `position:relative` with `top: 0; left: 0;`. Don't forget to set `z-index`, if you want to have better control over layering.

-A